# Cannot Remove List style type from sidebar in drupal

Tags: css, drupal

Hey I felt I was pretty familiar with CSS, but I cannot figure this out.

There is a list styling in the sidebar that I cannot remove on my site here:
[comptegrity](https://www.comptegrity.com/civicrm/event/info?reset=1&id=53)

Specifically the Upcoming Events section I am trying to remove from

I have tried adding !important in both the ul and the li.
Ive tried adding:
`body #doc_width #content_width ul (and li), ul, li{list-style:none !important}`

I have also done all this with setting content:none.

I cannot figure this out!? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

its an image....set background-image:none

Comment: ha, completely overlooked that. Thanks!

Comment: `list-style-image: none;`